# Programmatically set print page orientation to landscape

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

We have an ASP.NET C# web application with a "printer friendly" link. Is there a way to programmatically set the orientation to landscape, so the user can just press the print button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "No." It is a deliberate limitation of browsers that the page itself cannot override the user's print settings. This is to prevent abuse I would imagine and causes all sorts of headaches.

One possible work around would be to output your page as a PDF and present that. You *can* control the print settings for a PDF page.

Comment: +1 for the pdf methode. I had to use this at work and every body had acrobat reader...

Answer (score 8):

This is something that would have to be done on the client side (using JavaScript/CSS).

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have the ability to make this change.

CSS does have a means of specifying landscape printing via the @page directive:

```
@page {
    size: landscape;
}
```

CSS Paged Media is well supported by Chrome v15+ and Opera v15+, is partially supported by Firefox v19+, IE8+ and all versions of Edge. However it is not supported by Safari at all

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-paged-media

Comment: In 2022, in an ASP.Net WebApplication and C#, this worked for me in Chrome Version 103.0.5060.134 and Microsoft Edge Version 103.0.1264.71. I found that putting this into its own Stylesheet and then including that style sheet only in the <head> section of pages that needed to display (table, etc.) in landscape, it worked great.  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/PrintInLandscapeStyle.css" media="print" />

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no programmatic way to set orientation. It's entirely handled by the browser.

The best you can do is say "we recommend you print the page with Landscape (or Portrait)" and hope the user knows how to do it themselves.